# Playing Vector CANoe BLF/ASC file using CAPL

Tags: can-bus, canoe, canalyzer

I'd like to play a Vector CANoe BLF/ASC file from my CAPL srcipt. For some reason the Replay Block can not be used.
Is is possible to play a CANoe BLF/ASC file from the CAPL script?

Comment: What are the reasons for „the Replay Block can not be used“?

Comment: Replaying of the BLF file has to be started at a different moment in my simulation. The features of the Reply Block is known to me but for this simulation it is just unsuitable.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the CAPL command to replay a file:

```
dword StartReplayFile(char fileName[]);
```

> Starts playing the replay file with the name fileName.

(Taken from CANoe documentation).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

Log files are digitized version of your network traffic stored in the harddisk of the computer for future reference. One can use them to understand what was happened during measurement (that is achieved via offline analysis) another way is recreate the traffic that was happened during measurement (this is achieved via  replay block) other than these two we do not have need to play the files. Hence CAPL does not support playing files other than these to application